# What sort of power requirements are necessary to create an artificial magnetic shield around planetary & moon-sized bodies?

Tags: colonization, terraforming

I wonder how difficult it would be to create an artificial planetary magnetic field with generators? What power would they need?

The question is inspired by thinking about possible colonization of Jupiter's moons Io and Europa, which are located inside the Jovian radiation belt. Is it possible to create with easy means an artificial magnetic field such that it would shield the surfaces of these moons from radiation? Or would it require an astronomical amount of power?

By easy means I mean a device that would not require power greater than a normal industrial power plant, best of all, solar-powered or based on once-charged superconductor coils.

Comment: It would take a vast amount of power. You aren't going to get that from a solar collector or normal power plant.

Comment: Not quite astronomical. A terawatt would recreate the Earth's magnetic field. That's about 800 flux capacitors at 1.21 gigawatts each, or about 50 Three Gorges Dam-equivalents at 18.3 gigawatts each.

Comment: @David Hammen of course smaller planet would require less energy. Or one may choose to cover just some areas...

Comment: Fine. Scale it down by a factor of 800 to 1.21 gigawatts so all you need is one flux capacitor. Since we don't have a flux capacitor yet, you'll need 11,000 times the total generating power of the International Space Station.

Comment: @David Hammen but will this stop the penetrating radiation of the Jupiter's radiation belt? BTW, what is flux capacitor?

Comment: A flux capacitor is a fictional device from the movie series "Back to the Future" that needed 1.21 gigawatts to operate. I guess I should have said "Mr Fusion" instead of "flux capacitor"; it was Mr Fusion that supplied the 1.21 gigawatts needed by the flux capacitor. We don't have a flux capacitor and we don't have Mr Fusion, either. It sure would be nice to have Mr Fusion. But we don't. It's pure fiction.

Comment: Scaling down the Earth's magnetic field down by a factor of roughly 1000 results in something that is orders of magnitude out of reach. My answer of 11,000 Space Station equivalents was wrong; I didn't account for the distance of Jupiter from the Sun. You'll need about 300,000 Space Station equivalents to generate 1.21 gigawatts at Io or Europa. Will that do the trick? Jupiter's magnetic field is very large. 1.21 gigawatts might be enough to protect a smallish colony. Until we have Mr Fusion, that 1.21 gigawatts is out of reach. Even 1.21 megawatts at Jupiter's orbit is out of reach.

Comment: [Related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139750/how-much-power-would-be-needed-to-make-a-substitute-for-natural-earth-magnetic-f) on Physics.

Comment: @david, 1.21 gigawatts may be '300,000' space stations... but it's about 1/3rd of the Palo Verde's capacity.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - This question was about what's feasible in space. Building a Palo Verde-sized nuclear reactor in space will not be feasible for at least a generation to come, and most likely a lot more. Asking about what the world will look like a mere 25 years into the future is a dubious effort. Fifty years, and it's pure fiction. It's not science because it's not falsifiable. (You can say almost anything. How can we you wrong? We can't, so it's not science.) Past efforts to predict fifty years ahead have proven to be incredibly wrong. It's a futile effort.

Comment: @DavidHammen then simply say it's entirely possible - we have power plants that output more than that on earth today, however it's not likely to be feasible in our lifetimes and speculation beyond that belongs in SE:WorldBuilding not SE:Space.

Comment: @NPSF3000 - Exactly. This question, along with similar ones, are best suited for that site rather than this one. A nice delineation: This site is a nice home for questions about past, present, and near-term future space exploration. Anything beyond a few decades into the future belongs in that other site.